How to access the URL field used by the macOS Calendar on Android?
I use the calendar application that's built in macOS. Events created there have a URL field. How do I access that field from an Android phone?

A sample event with an URL created on macOS, exported from Google Calendar:
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20210323
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20210324
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=2
DTSTAMP:20240410T225451Z
UID:179C1961-1EA6-439E-BD91-774CDEFB6CE9
URL:https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/256767/edit
CREATED:20210309T184613Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20240402T191532Z
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:How to access the URL field used by the MacOS Calendar on Android?
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR


I would first check how the URL is save din the calendar entry. Go to https://calendar.google.com open settings (cog wheel in the upper right -> Settings) and export your calendar. Unpack the ZIP file you get and open the ical file in a text editor, search an calendar entry with an URL and see how Apple has saved the URL.

It seems like the URL field is not supported by Google on Android. Even if you create an calendar entry with an URL using an app like Etar the URL field vanishes and is never synced to the Google Calendar (missing in the Google Calendar Export via web UI). There is an older question on SO that also mentions what I noticed: Is there any way to use a URL field across Google Calendar and iOS calendar

@Robert It works between my Macs when I synch via Google Calendar. This sample event was extracted from the Google Calendar web UI export. The problem is that the Android calendar apps (and Google calendar web UI) don't support it.
